# Formatar data usando HtmlHelper

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Preciso que a data da minha model seja exibido no formato "dd/mm/aaaa" na minha view, hoje ele exibe no formato "aaaa-mm-dd".
Segue o trecho do meu código:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DataNascimento)
```

Como implemento?

Answer (score 0):

Há algumas opções de serem feitas, segue algumas delas

```
@Html.Label(item.DataNascimento.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"))
```

ou

```
@Html.Label(item.DataNascimento.ToShortDateString())
```

Ou

Na sua classe adicione a *annotation* e assim você poderá usar o `@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DataNascimento)` que ele irá respeitar a *annotation*

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
public DateTime DataNascimento{ get; set; }
```